# How to count elements in the array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make an Array of 100 elements from  numbers[1,10] and then count how many of every number is in that Array. How can I do it? I have the Array with random numbers:

```
function random(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for(var y=0 ; y<100 ; y++)
{
   tab[y]=random(1, 10);
}
```

but I don't know how to search for every number.

Comment: sort array uisng var sorted_arr = yourarrayname.sort(); then count it will be easier

Comment: buddy, @heylala, check out link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_length_array

Comment: buddy, @Victor, should probably read the whole question instead of just the title.

Comment: okay, got it @squint!

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var tab = [];
for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
    tab[y] = random(1, 10);
}

//counter the instances of each number
var counter = {};
for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    if (!counter[tab[i]]) {
        counter[tab[i]] = 0;
    }
    counter[tab[i]]++;
}

console.log(counter)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rs174yq7/)